# AWS MetaData Service - how can I alias 169.254.169.254?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, metadata

In order to add another security layer to my IMDS, I would like to change http://169.254.169.254 to a unique address in my ec2. How can it be done in simple Linux commands?

Comment: You can't, because 169.254.169.254 is a special address provided by AWS for each VM. And even if you could change that, it wouldn't increase security.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you’ll want to take a look at instead is the relatively recently introduced IMDSv2:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/defense-in-depth-open-firewalls-reverse-proxies-ssrf-vulnerabilities-ec2-instance-metadata-service/

This will provide you with additional protections that are fully supported by AWS SDKs and other tools.